# send data method GET in dart (Flutter)

Tags: http, flutter, dart, dio

already use http, Uri parse......

[image: login working, get addresses not work]

login working, get addresses not work

Answer (score 0):

Here you go to use dio for network call:

```
try {
  _dio.options.contentType = Headers.jsonContentType;
  Response response = await _dio.post(
      baseUrl + '/verify-otp',
      data: {"activation_token": ""}
  );
  return response;
} catch (error, stacktrace) {
  print("Exception occured: $error stackTrace: $stacktrace");
  return error;
}
```